# Ruby on Rails: doing a find on reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reference

I have two tables (nodes and agents). `nodes` are belong_to `agents`. I have a script that is pulling the Rails project into it and I'm trying to pull in values from the ActiveRecord. I'm assuming what I'm asking should work whether it's in a controller or view -or- in a cli script. So, my script looks thusly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require '/Users/hseritt/devel/rails_projects/monitor_app/config/environment'

banner = "Banner running..."
script_dir = '/devel/rails_projects/monitor_app/monitor/bin'

class Runner

attr_accessor :banner, :agents, :agent_module, :nodes

def initialize(banner, script_dir)
    @banner = banner
    @agents = Agent.all
    @nodes = Node.all
    @script_dir = script_dir
end

def run
    puts @banner
    @agents.each do |agent|
        if agent.active?
            agent_module = '%s/%s' % [@script_dir, agent.name]
            require agent_module

            @nodes.each do |node|
                if node.agent == agent
                    puts node.name
                end
            end
                            #
            # HERE IS THE ISSUE:
            # ns = Node.find_by_agent_id(agent.id)
            # ns.each do |node|
            #   puts node.name
            # end
            # 
            # yields this error:
            #`method_missing': undefined method `each' for #<Node:0x007fe4dc4beba0> (NoMethodError)
            # I would think `ns` here would be itterable but it doesn't seem that way.
        end
    end
end
end

if $0 == __FILE__
    runner = Runner.new(banner, script_dir)
    runner.run  
end
```

So, this is in the run method. The block that is not commented out but of course this is not a good solution since each time you iterate through agents you'll have to iterate through nodes each time. The block that is commented out seemed logical to me but throws an error. I'm having trouble probably googling the right thing here I think. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

```
Node.find_all_by_agent_id
```

if you don't use "all", it takes the first element only

Comment: Thanks much fotanus. That did the trick. Coming from Django-land, I figured I was missing something simple.

Comment: welcome to Rails, you are going to like it - has its pros and cons, but you should be aware of this by now.